# DAX calculation - Calculated field is not working while multiple selections in the dropdown

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals, daxstudio

I have a problem while selecting multiple years in the dropdown. I have 2 DAX measure calculations which is working fine while one selection in the dropdown, however, it provides blank values while multiple selections in the dropdown. How can I fix this issue?
Here is my DAX calculation -

```
                    COUNT(table[id]),  
                     FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office]),
                     table[Fiscal_Year] < SELECTEDVALUE(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
                     (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = blank() ||
                     table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= SELECTEDVALUE(table[Fiscal_Year])
                     )))
```

what changes do I need to make to work it for multiple selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with multiple selections in a dropdown for a DAX measure in Power BI, the function `SELECTEDVALUE` might not work as expected, since it is designed to return a single value. When multiple values are selected, `SELECTEDVALUE` returns a blank.

```
Cal = CALCULATE(
        COUNT(table[id]),
        FILTER(
            ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office]),
            table[Fiscal_Year] IN VALUES(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
            (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = BLANK() ||
             table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]))
        )
)
```

Comment: Bedhiari - Thanks for the explanation! I need count of all ids that is less than the selected fiscal year on the dropdown. For example, for 2023 - I want all the years count less than 2023.
But MAX function will start counting from 2024 always. I want calculation to read the condition for greater than or less than the "selected fiscal year" on the dropdown. How can I modify above expression?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace `SELECTEDVALUE` with either `MIN` or `MAX` with a range conditional if that is what is needed. Eg `MIN((table[Fiscal_Year]) <= x && x <=  MAX((table[Fiscal_Year])`.

`SELECTEDVALUE` only returns one unique value and if more than one value is found it returns `BLANK()`.

Comment: Thanks, Sam for the quick reply and the explanation! 
I need count of all ids that is less than the selected fiscal year on the dropdown. For example, for 2023 - I want all the years count less than 2023. But MAX function will start counting from 2024 always. I want calculation to read the condition for greater than or less than the "selected fiscal year" on the dropdown. How can I modify above expression?

Comment: CALCULATE(
                                    COUNT(table[id]),  
                     FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office]),
                     table[Fiscal_Year] <  MAX(table[Fiscal_Year]) &&
                     (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = blank() ||
                     table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] >= MAX(table[Fiscal_Year])
                     ))
This is what I changed in the syntax but numbers are off. It works with the multiple selections though.

Comment: What do you want the calculation to do when there are multiple selection? Count between min and max of the selection or only count per year selected?